# Specific time delay in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, timing, machine-code

In a vocatinal class I am taking, We use a sub-routine like the one below as a time delay.

```
      push ax
      push bx
      mov ax, 1000
B---> mov bx, FFFF
A---> nop
      dec bx
      jnz (A)
      dec ax
      jnz (B)
      pop bx
      pop ax
      ret
```

Where (1000) and (FFFF) are fluid, hexadecimal, 4-digit values.

I was hoping somebody could help me accurately time something with this program. (EX: 10 seconds) If possible, please include an equation for my class and I to use.

Comment: Providing a reliable way to measure elapsed time is the job of an operating system, not of assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this code for timing, you need to know the duration of the loop itself; there are multiple ways to do this:

1. Use the [Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) to look up the timings of each instruction.
2. Use the `rdtsc` instruction to measure the clock cycles

In either case, you'll need to divide by the CPU's clock rate to get the time in seconds.